# Simple inequality involving $\max(\cdot)$

Tags: inequality

Let $x_1, \ldots, x_n$ be real numbers. Is it true that

\begin{equation}
\max_{1 \leq i \leq n} |x_i| = \max \{ \max_{1 \leq i \leq n} x_i, \max_{1 \leq i \leq n} -x_i\}  \ ?
\end{equation}

My intuition is that the maximum in absolute value is either the smallest negative or the biggest positive number among $x_1, \ldots, x_n$, which motivates the given equation.

Any feedback is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
\max_{1 \leq i \leq n} |x_i| &= \max_{1 \leq i \leq n} \left(\max\{x_i,-x_i\}\right)\\
&=\max\left\{ \{x_i,1 \leq i \leq n\}\bigcup\{-x_i,1 \leq i \leq n\}\right\}\\
&= \max \left\{ \max_{1 \leq i \leq n} x_i, \max_{1 \leq i \leq n} -x_i\right\}.  \ 
\end{align}